# what is the right-click-on-window-titlebar menu called ? is there a winapi call to get a handle of this menu?

Tags: winapi, menu, window, windows-xp

The same menu shows up when top left icon in title bar is clicked by left mouse and again it shows up with right-clicking on the window representation in the taskbar. Ist there a way to get to the handle of this menu, add my own commands ?

Comment: And Alt+Space displays it too. This can be combined with a single character (the underlined one) to invoke any action in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok , I found it, it is called [System Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647985.aspx)